# How can I have multiline error in ShopifyApp.flashError()

Tags: javascript, shopify

Shopify has a very useful [method](https://help.shopify.com/api/sdks/shopify-apps/embedded-app-sdk/methods#shopifyapp-flasherror-message) in its `Embedded App SDK` for showing errors on a small red floating modal : `ShopifyApp.flashError("Your error");`

My problem is that I cannot have multiline errors in it. I have tried `\n`, `/n`, `/r`, `\r`, `<br />` and `&#013` for having `newline`. None worked! Any Ideas?

Comment: Have you peeked into the source code for the `flashError` method? The answer might be there.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Forty3. But I believe we don't have access to Shopify source code!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like ShopifyApp.flashError makes a call to postMessage:

```
e.postMessage = function(e, t) {
  var r;
  return null == t && (t = {}), r = JSON.stringify({
      message: e,
      data: t
    }), 
    n("client sent " + r + " to " + this.shopOrigin),
    window.parent.postMessage(r, this.shopOrigin), 
    null != t ? t.callbackId : void 0
}, e.flashNotice = function(e) {
  return this.postMessage("Shopify.API.flash.notice", {
    message: e
  })
}, e.flashError = function(e) {
  return this.postMessage("Shopify.API.flash.error", {
    message: e
  })
}
```

So, if you can find the bit of logic that is listening for messages sent to "Shopify.API.flash.error" you can find the code which renders the message. However, given the `r = JSON.stringify({ message: e, data: t})` call, I suspect you are out of luck insofar as passing in a special enough character to invoke a newline.

Answer (score 0):

No, there currently isn't a way to do this. If you look at the Shopify page source code, you can find the template used to render alerts:

```html
<script type="text/template" data-template-name="alert">
    ...
    <p>[%= message %]</p>
    ...
</script>
```

So your message is being put into a regular paragraph, without anything fancy like `white-space: pre-line`. And since text inserted into templates isn't allowed to contain HTML tags, you cannot use a `<br>` tag either.